# Looking for an explanation on the purpose of making a function like this in js

Tags: javascript

I tried to search for an answer but without even knowing what this is called, not really sure what to search for. I am curious as to the full purpose of using a function like this. I know the fat arrow part of it is an anonymous function.

```
((() => {
    // code
}))();
```

Comment: It’s an IIFE, immediately invoked function expression.

Comment: It's an IIFE, with one too many pairs of parentheses.

Comment: To add to Dave, it would also be useful when you want to execute a piece of async code without making an async function

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript (has a list under "(function(){…})()  —  IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)")

Comment: Thanks everyone. Very helpful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called Immediately Invoked Function Expression, or IIFE in short. It's mostly used to avoid polluting the global namespace. You can read more about it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

Comment: Much appreciated. I will upvote soon as I get another point.